# In swift how do I change the color of a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have created a game with an `SKSpriteNode` that is black and when the user touches the screen I would like for the `SKSpriteNode` to change to white. I have googled everything I can and attempted lots of different strategies with no luck. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's the code for my scene:

```
var blackBird = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //Black Bird
    var blackBirdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"blackbird")
    blackBirdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    blackBird = SKSpriteNode(texture: blackBirdTexture)
    blackBird.setScale(0.5)
    blackBird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y:
        self.frame.size.height * 0.6)

    blackBird.physicsBody =
        SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:blackBird.size.height/2.0)
    blackBird.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    blackBird.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(blackBird)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    blackBird.color = .whiteColor()
    blackBird.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `color` property on `SKSpriteNode`, for example:

```
sprite.color = .whiteColor()
```

Bear in mind, if your `SKSpriteNode` has a texture you'll need to set the `colorBlendFactor` to a non-zero value to see your color. From the [`SKSpriteNode` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/colorBlendFactor) on `colorBlendFactor`:

> The value must be a number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive. The default
>   value (0.0) indicates the color property is ignored and that the
>   texture’s values should be used unmodified. **For values greater than
>   0.0, the texture is blended with the color before being drawn to the scene.**

---

If you want to animate the color change you can use an `SKAction`:

```
let colorize = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.whiteColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 5)
sprite.runAction(colorize)
```

From the [`SKAction` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:) on `colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:`

> This action can only be executed by an SKSpriteNode object. When the
>   action executes, the sprite’s color and colorBlendFactor properties
>   are animated to their new values.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm trying the first option you gave me like this:        sprite.color = .whiteColor()
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0                                    
It's not working for me, am I doing it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any errors? Is it not changing color? Your sprite's texture isn't black is it?

Comment: Sorry, no errors it's just not changing color. My sprite is an image i uploaded that is currently black and I'm trying to change it to white on touch. I'm not sure if that means its current texture is black? Also, I did try the second option you gave me and it did work by the image slowly becoming white and then going back to black. I just need the image to stay white. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you think you could post the relevant code - the creation of the `SKSpriteNode`; where you're trying to set the color and in which method?

Comment: I've added your answer as an edit to your question - that's where it belongs really (you should remove your answer too) :) Regarding your issue - is the `blackbird` image black coloured?

Comment: White blended with an image produces the original image. You'll have better luck with `.redColor`.

Comment: Not only did trying a .redColor() not work but that is not what i need. I need my black image to turn white and stay white. Thanks though.

Answer (score 11):

Copying an answer found on another forum:

> The black parts of your image won't be blended, I can't see what the alpha is from your image, but if your image was just a black outline with a solid white center, if you blend, you'll see the color. If you want just the outline to blend, you need to create a white outline.
>   With blending, you can set color to blend to black, but you can't blend to white.

link: https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/30hr88/colorizing_a_skspritenode_doesnt_seems_to_work_as/

Comment: Sorry, just edited. The quote is the part that allowed me solving the same issue as described in this topic.