# Swift 3 Change Hue Of Sprite

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sprite

In my game, i have a wizard sprite.

[image: wizard]

I would like to be able to change the colour of this sprite programatically so put a faded color over the top to change the color.

So when the player changes the character, the sprite color changes.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Read these : http://stackoverflow.com/q/24985003/3402095, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31484582/3402095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just convert the colorable portion to greyscale and use SKAction.colorize the sprite.

this works very well, I use it all the time, however you may have to create a wizard overlay of the red and yellow parts so they don't get colorized as well

[image: white wizard]